# Focus input after alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to draw `n inputs` this is the reason of why my inputs do not have `ID`, I use the following function to validate the typed value on every input after `unfocus`:

```
$('#Div').on('blur', '.inputbtn', function () {
    validarType.bind(this)();
});

function validarType() {

    var xd = this.value;
    if (xd != "") {
        bootbox.confirm({
            message: "Value: " + xd + " is correct?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'Yes',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'No',
                    className: 'btn-danger'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result == true) {

                }
                else {
                    bootbox.alert("Check your data.");
                    //Focus Here
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

What I want to do is for example type information on the first input, after change focus to other input alert message is going to appear, if I click on `No` option I want to focus that input again, but like I said, I do not have any `ID` to do something like `$('#Myinput').focus()` in other case maybe could be possible do this with `'$(this).focus()'`, what can I do?

Here is a [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbWYxd)

Comment: You need to save the "this" `function validarType() {
   var thisField = this;
    var xd = thisField.value; ............ thisField.focus(); // Focus Here`

Comment: Is this not a question about event.target rather than a classic JS 'this' confusion?